# R, obtain complete file path string in files names in Windows (spaces and more)

Tags: r, windows, file

Certainly an old issue, but I was not able to find a solution (maybe there are none). On Unix it is straight forward to use the R function `file.path` to obtain the path to some file. How can the same thing be done under Windows when spaces in paths return with `~` . 
If I need to write, say the path to Rscript.exe to a file, this would work on unix:

```
x <- list.files(R.home("bin"), full.names = T, pattern = "Rscript")
writeLines(x, con = "path_to_rscript.txt")
```

On Windows the result is:

`C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe`

Where I would have wanted something like:

`C:/Program Files/R-3.5.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe`

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior (and what is it with the capitalized PROGRA ?).

Comment: *"what is it with the capitalized PROGRA ?"* Try `dir \ /X` at the command line.

Comment: What's wrong with C:/PROGRA~1? Did you try using it?

Comment: Yes one can use the windows shortened style in some regards but not in others. I wanted to have the complete path as a string, that is, the complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, checkout [normalizePath](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/normalizePath):

```
normalizePath(path, winslash = "\\", mustWork = NA)
```

which states explicitly:

> On Windows it converts relative paths to absolute paths, **converts**
>   **short names for path elements to long names** and ensures the separator
>   is that specified by winslash. It will match paths case-insensitively
>   and return the canonical case. UTF-8-encoded paths not valid in the
>   current locale can be used.